# подключение БД Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Подскажите плиз.Выложил сайт на хостинг не могу подключиться к базе данных. Выдает вот такую ошибку:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [2003] Can't connect to MySQL server on '217.182.***.***' (111 "Connection refused")' in /var/www/bukovsit/data/www/*****.h1n.ru/components/Db.php:13 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/bukovsit/data/www/******.h1n.ru/components/Db.php(13): PDO->__construct('mysql:host=217....', '*******', '********') #1 /var/www/bukovsit/data/www/******.h1n.ru/models/Category.php(12): Db::getConnection() #2 /var/www/bukovsit/data/www/*******.h1n.ru/controllers/SiteController.php(12): Category::getCategoriesList() #3 [internal function]: SiteController->actionIndex() #4 /var/www/bukovsit/data/www/*******.h1n.ru/components/Router.php(61): call_user_func_array(Array, Array) #5 /var/www/bukovsit/data/www/*******.h1n.ru/index.php(19): Router->run() #6 {main} thrown in /var/www/bukovsit/data/www/******.h1n.ru/components/Db.php on line 13

Comment: *"Connection refused"* - вот и весь разговор. Проверяй существование пользователя, имеющего право именно с хоста, где вертится PHP, подключаться к MySQL-серверу.